# Merge table cells with specific class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html-table

I'm trying to merge table cells which has the same class.

```js
$(function () {
  $('table tbody tr').each(function () {
    var colspan = $(this).find('td.row').length
    if (colspan > 1) {
      $(this).find('td.row:first').attr('colspan', colspan)
      $(this).find('td.row:not(:first)').remove()
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Result of above code is as bellow.

[image]

Result without merging:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what do you want to do when the cells being merged have different data values inside them?

Comment: can you share css as well?

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil CSS is not relevant here.

Comment: @blackpen no,i just wan to merge them wether it contains any data values or not

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil there is no any css applyed except for setting background color to cell who has class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function () {
  $('table tr').each(function () {
    let $firstRow
       ,colspan = 0
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('row')) {
        // Save the first cell with class in $firstRow, remove the rest
        colspan === 0 ? $firstRow = $(this) : $(this).remove()
        // Count the number of cells
        colspan++
      } else if (colspan > 0) {
        // Assign the colspan and reset the counter
        $firstRow.attr('colspan', colspan)
        colspan = 0
      }
    })
    if (colspan > 0) {
      $firstRow.attr('colspan', colspan)
      colspan = 0
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks it is what excalty i was expectiong it is working fine but in script code at  (let $firstRow) there is a red line below Let  keyword and it is showing syntax error ,when am hovering mouse over it

Comment: @Ma6139735 `let` keyword is a new JavaScript feature. If it's not working, try replacing it with `var`.

Comment: thanks,actually that Let was also working i was just curious because it was showing error over there,but this var keyword has resolved that one,thanks really